# session.getAttribute("key") returns -1

Tags: session, session-variables

I have a session variable called "tempSessionKey". 
At first I did not set any value in this variable.

But in JSP page I am trying to get value by : session.getAttribute("tempSessionKey")

I expect a NULL value but always get -1.

What is the problem ???

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: share your code as well.

Comment: here's my code:

int count = 0;
if(session.getAttribute("tempSessionKey") == null){
 count = 0;
}